# Changing a variable changes another variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let a=['one','two'];
let b=a;
b.push('three')

console.log(a,b);
```

In the above program changing b's value also changes a's value, why?

Also tell me the most effective way to solve this issue.

Comment: You're not changing the variable, you're changing the array object. Which is referenced from two variables.

Comment: Please read about "reference variables" in JavaScript.

Comment: @JLRishe Did you mean "reference values"?